# Send data to Influxdb using Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, influxdb

I'm trying to send the data to Influxdb using Google app script with the below code but I always run into `Bad Request` error. The same works when I send the data using the Influxdb API. Unable to figure out what am I missing here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
function dataentry() {

var response;

var tags = {
"PROGRAM":"Migration"
}

var fields = {
"TESTED_BY": "Peter",
"RESULT":1,
"STATUS":"Fail"
}

var data = {"measurement":"testing","tags":tags,"time":,"fields":fields};

Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));

var options = {
"method" : "post",
"muteHttpExceptions" : true,
"contentType": "application/json",
"payload" : JSON.stringify(data)
//"payload" : data
};

try {
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8086/write?db=mydbb', options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

catch(err) {
Logger.log(err);
}
}
```

Output: `Exception: Bad request: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8086/write?db=mydbb`

Example of the Influxdb http write API -

```
curl -i -XPOST http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8086/write?db=mydbb --data-binary "testing,PROGRAM=Migration TESTED_BY=\"Peter\",STATUS=\"Fail\",RESULT=1"
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about `http://xx.xx.xx.xx` in your script and your actual situation from your question, when I saw your sample curl command, `http://localhost` is used. If you want to access to your local server from Google Apps Script, the your server can be accessed from outside using an URL?

Comment: Yeah, that can be accessed, I just wrote it so that I don't have to display the actual IP address. The error seems to be with the format of the request body which I am not able to figure out

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to discuss by supposing that you can directly access to you IP address with POST method. In that case, in your question, a sample curl command is shown. But it seems that the request body is different from your Google Apps Script. How about this? Can you provide one more sample curl, that you confirmed it worked, using the request body of Google Apps Script?

Comment: `curl -i -XPOST 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8086/write?db=mydb'
--data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000'` - this curl command will work when you have localhost or the ip address with the fact that influx db is running in your system. The same command when converted into Google App scrirpt gives me Bad Request error

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about the difference of request body between your curl command and your Google Apps Script. I apologize for this again.

Comment: i updated the curl command to match with my google app script

Comment: @Tanaike - thanks for your response to this. All I'm trying to do and my requirement here is to send the data to Influxdb using the google app script. so I need to convert the given curl command (which works when executed in the cmd given the fact that influxdb is running in our system) to the google app script code and execute it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. When I saw your updated curl command, it seems that it is different from the request body of your Google Apps Script. So I would like to confirm your current situation and goal. You have already confirmed that your updated curl command worked. And, you want to convert your updated curl command to Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yeah, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, the key and value of the sent form data is `testing,PROGRAM` and `"Migration TESTED_BY=\"Peter\",STATUS=\"Fail\",RESULT=1"`, respectively. Is this valid values for the specification of the API you want to use?

Comment: yeah, that's correct. Please refer https://community.influxdata.com/t/sending-data-from-google-scripts-to-influx-missing-tag-value/11143/5 as well as i just pasted a the google app script

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I access to the URL, I cannot see the page. I apologize for this.

Comment: ok, not sure what am i missing from my side executing this script. Every attempt i made resulted in Bad Exception error. Please refer this Influxdb docs on understanding the write calls - https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/guides/writing_data/

Comment: Thank you for replying. When your updated curl command is converted to Google Apps Script, in this case, it seems that `db=mydbb` and `"testing,PROGRAM=Migration TESTED_BY=\"Peter\",STATUS=\"Fail\",RESULT=1"` are sent as query parameter and form. When this request is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows. `const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8086/write?db=mydbb", {payload: {"testing,PROGRAM": "Migration TESTED_BY=\"Peter\",STATUS=\"Fail\",RESULT=1"}});`.

Comment: But I'm not sure whether your IP address and port number can be used with UrlFetchApp. So when this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: do i need to add any additional headers for the above request?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample curl command, it seems no request header. How about this?

Comment: the curl command doesn't need any headers.. it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank you for replying. My proposal script converts your curl command. So I have no information about the header. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can you provide other sample curl command including the request header that you have already confirmed it works?